# How do we retrieve a Boolean with exists in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to check weather an account associated with the same username already exists or not. I am using the exist method to check but I keep getting a large object instead of a Boolean value.

```js
async checkExisting(username,userCollection) { //WORK ON ISSUE WITH VERIFYING
        const check = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let value = userCollection.exists({username})
            console.log(value);
            // if(userCollection.exists({username})) {
            //     reject("Username taken")
            // }

            resolve("Username avaliable")
        })

        return check;
    },
```

Comment: Please show us the value of the "*large object*" that you printed. It should be pretty clear what it represents and where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. It's just what you write in resolve is returned.
And no need to make the function `async` as you're already returning a Promise. So where you call this function there just keep `await` as follows

```js
await checkExisting('username', 'collection')

checkExisting(username, userCollection)
{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  userCollection
   .exists({username})
   .then((value) => {
    if (value) {
     resolve(true)
    }
    resolve(false)
   })
   .catch((err) => reject(err))
 })
}
```

Note: You can use either promise or async-await syntax; both ways are correct. However, never combine these two concepts as it will give unexpected output.

Answer (score 0):

`userCollection.exists({username})` returns a query that you never ran. You need to actually execute it and wait for the result. Also avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). Just do

```
async checkExisting(username,userCollection) {
    const check = await userCollection.exists({username})
    if (check) {
        throw new Error("Username taken");
    }
    return "Username avaliable";
},
```